# What is the time for the beginning of a day? \formattime{00}{00}{00} or \formattime{24}{00}{00}

Tags: datetime

I have set `\settimeformat{ampmtime}`, and I want to print a time which is the very beginning of the day.

For  `\formattime{00}{00}{00}`, it gives me **12:00am**; for `\formattime{24}{00}{00}`, it gives me **12:00pm**.

Now I am confused...

Comment: It is as it is supposed to be :). 0000h (12:00am) is the beginning of the day.  When you say 2400h is midnight, which theoretically belongs to the night that is passing by.  Your confusion comes from the fact that there is only one 12:00pm-> noon.  12:00am is the first hour of the next day.

Comment: What you're encountering may be a British English versus American English thing. At least in the U.S. English usage it's not uncommon to (a) treat "12 p.m." and "12 Noon" interchangeably and (b) say "12 a.m. on the next day" for `{24}{00}{00}`. You've probably already noticed that `\formattime{12}{00}{00}` generates the output **12:00 Noon**, which is unambiguous. The rendering of the time string `{24}{00}{00}` as **12:00 pm** is maybe best thought of as a *limit* as the 24-hour clock *ticks up* to midnight.

Comment: yes, US time is confusing. Last time I bought a movie ticket which starts on 12 pm, and I arrived at 12 in the noon. Everybody laughed...:(

Comment: I think it's simply wrong; AFAIK, 12:00pm is noon. The test  made by `datetime` is too simplistic.

Comment: @egreg -- this is a discussion i've had before.  12:00 is so eminently confusing that insurance companies specify that their policies take effect at 12:01 a.m.  yes, `datetime` is probably too simplistic.  i happen to believe that 12:00 a.m. is the end of the a.m., thus "noon".  and 12:00 p.m = 00:00 = "midnight".  always safer to say explicitly "noon" or "midnight" (in a language-appropriate way, of course), which is what is done for ams meeting programs, or specify that you're using a 24-hour clock.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The start of the day is 00:00, the end is 24:00.